# substitute duplicate value with null SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the following data :

| orderid | item_amount | total_bill_amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2 | 8 |
| 123 | 6 | 8 |
| 455 | 4 | 11 |
| 455 | 6 | 11 |
| 455 | 1 | 11 |

I want to substitute duplicate value for `total_bill_amount` with **null** ad keep the first record always with a value and anything after with null. Example of how i want to see the data :

| orderid | item_amount | total_bill_amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2 | 8 |
| 123 | 6 | null |
| 455 | 4 | 11 |
| 455 | 6 | null |
| 455 | 1 | null |

Note that my **MySQL version is 5.7**, so I can't use any window functions in **MySQL 8**.

Comment: A table is a set of unordered rows, there is no "first" record in your data; OrderId 455 you want to keep item_amount 4 but not 6 or 1 - you need some way of ordering the data to meet your criteria.

Comment: actually the order will be according to the order_id, first row for order_id should show the total bill amount and rest of rows for the order_id should be null

Comment: you have not understood. OrderId is not unique, there is no ordering within each group.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` with a subquery:

```
with to_r(rnum, id, a, t) as (
   select row_number() over (order by o.orderid), o.* from orders o 
)
select r.id, r.a, case when 
       (select sum(r1.t = r.t and r1.id = r.id and r.rnum >= r1.rnum) from to_r r1) > 1 
       then null else r.t end
from to_r r
```